# Envoy Laravel "EOF-LARAVEL-ENVOY: command not found" error

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, laravel-envoy

I'm trying to do deploy Laravel application with using Envoy, but I get error:

```
[deployer@xxxx]: Cloning into '/var/www/xxxx/releases/20171214110823'...
[deployer@xxxx]: bash: line 5: EOF-LARAVEL-ENVOY: command not found
[✗] This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.
```

My tasks looks like:

```
@story('deploy')
clone_repository
run_composer
update_symlinks
@endstory

@task('clone_repository')
echo 'Cloning repository'
[ -d {{ $releases_dir }} ] || mkdir {{ $releases_dir }}
git clone --depth 1 {{ $repository }} {{ $new_release_dir }}
@endtask

@task('run_composer')
echo "Starting deployment ({{ $release }})"
cd {{ $new_release_dir }}
composer install --prefer-dist --no-scripts -q -o
@endtask
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: have you tried defining task before the run_composer as `composer global require laravel/envoy` actually task runner depends on coposer package and if you wan to run the task you have to have those packages installed already.

Comment: @webDev thanks for your reply. I have tried, but I solved this in a different way. I figured out that problem was with ssh-client, because this Envoy was called from docker image php-alpine. This image use ssh client which not doesn't support multiline command via ssh. I solved it by change docker image to php-fpm